# Is MySQL showing wrong percentage?

Tags: mysql

Im currently trying to get the percentage difference from the same column, but with different dates.

This is the query I'm currently testing:

```
SELECT     curr.slug,
           curr.senaste * 100 / NULLIF(prev.senaste, 0) as percentage
FROM       aktier AS curr
INNER JOIN aktier AS prev
        ON curr.slug = prev.slug
WHERE      date(prev.timestamp) = '2015-11-16'
AND        date(curr.timestamp) = CURDATE()
AND        curr.slug = 'abb-ltd'
```

If i run this query i will get the result: 103.14465408805032

But, if I run query  `SELECT senaste FROM aktier WHERE slug = 'abb-ltd'`i get theses two values:
`159,4` `164,1`

And when i run `1-(159,4/164,1)` on my calculator i will get this result: `0,2864`.

Whats wrong with the current set up? And: how do i get the result from the query to show 2,9%?

The column senaste is a `varchar(5)` with `utf8_unicode_ci`.

SQL-fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a859

Answer (score 0):

Your column `senaste` is a `VARCHAR(5)` containing data like `'159,4'`. `VARCHAR` fields should not be used to store numbers, especially if you intend on having MySQL run math on the values.

You should instead be using a `DECIMAL(10,1)` (assuming you only want a single decimal digit) and you should be using a period, not a comma in your number format. (eg, `'159.4'`)

Comment: That solved the problem with the calculation! but how do i show the result rounded to one decimal?